# Msbuild copying copy to output file of a different project to another project's output dir

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild

I have a solution with two independent projects

1. **A.csproj**  `<OutputType>Exe</OutputType>`
2. **B.csproj** which has a.txt ( marked as copy to output) . `<OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>`

While building the solution a.txt is not being copied to **A.csproj** bin folder and this is perfect. But when building the solution with msbuild a.txt is being copied to **A.csproj**  bin folder which I did not expect.

Because of this wix installer build is failing but that is secondary.

What is the way to attain the same behavior in msbuild as of visual studio build?

solution in v12.0

Msbuild command line

> MSBuild.exe  /t:Build /v:m /ds /p:Configuration=Release

Comment: MSBuild should have the same behavior as Visual Studio. This issue should be related to your project, could you please share us the project type of those two project and the build command line when you build with MSBuild, or you can share a sample solution which could reproduce this issue?

Comment: @LeoLiu-MSFT : I have updated the post. Let me know if we want further details

Comment: Sorry late reply, I still could not reproduce this issue, would you mind share us a test sample project via onedrive? Thanks.